# Identifying plague affecting chrysalidocarpus lutescens

Tags: identification, diseases

Here a close picture of what it is attacking this poor plant:

[image]

I tried to spot movement among the white spots but there is none so my first suspect is some kind of fungi...

I applied some polyvalent insecticide/fungi treatment with no avail, it seems I need something more aggressive or more specific to this plague.

Can anyone make some suggestions?

Comment: Excellent photo! I suspect that the pests on the stem are not fungi but either scale or mealybug; other posters here may be able to provide a more definitive answer. What is your location in the world?

Comment: Thanks @Jurp for the suggestion. I suspected fungi only because I was not able to see any movement but as I am not an expert I can be totally wrong :P I am located in Madrid, Spain where the weather is normally warm and semi-arid.